# Has anybody made a german config file for the GhostDoc AddIn?

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, ghostdoc

Has anybody made a german version of the GhostDoc template textes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, GhostDoc bases its processing on a hard-coded set of parsing rules based on programmer-English conventions. I've written an alternative add-in (AtomineerUtils) which uses an Xml-based rules file that is language independent, so it would be very easy to convert the rules for use in a different language.

For more details, see http://www.atomineerutils.com/

Comment: The only "English-specific" thing that is currently hard-coded is the "Plural" command. If the language rules aren't too complex then I'm happy to try to add support for automated pluralisation for other languages too.